# pause method cordova in ionic app not working as expected

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework, pause

I'm stuck trying to do something when entering the pause mode on ionic, the log works when pausing and resuming BUT on the pause I want to call a service which will save in backend the status of the app, if its I background or not, the problem is that the call takes more time so that call will be pending forever, is there a way to delay de app to leave like ionDidLeav but for the whole app, or using the angular lifecycle but the ngDestroy doesn't work , I just need more time so the call arrives in the backend to save the data

```
platform.ready().then(() => {
      if (platform.is('ios')) {
        // document.addEventListener('resign', this.onPause, false);
        // document.addEventListener('active', this.onResume, false);
        document.addEventListener("pause", function() {
          // make a call from service will be pending forever
          console.log("paused")
      }, false);
      document.addEventListener("resume", function() {
        // not firing
        console.log("resumed")
    }, false);
      } else {
        platform.pause.subscribe(() => this.onPause());
        platform.resume.subscribe(() => this.onResume());
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could use [`BackgroundMode`](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/background-mode). Linked docs are for ionic 4, but if you are using ionic 3, docs can be found **[here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/v3/native/background-mode/)**.

You don't need to run the background mode for as long as the app is on pause, you can just wait until the request is completed, or errors out. So follow the steps from the documentation on how to install it.

```ts
import { BackgroundMode } from '@ionic-native/background-mode/ngx';
```

and mark it in the providers array in your module. Also import it in your component and inject it to your constructor, for example as `backgroundMode`

Then just use it your your `pause` function:

```ts
document.addEventListener("pause", () => {
  this.backgroundMode.enable(); // enable it!
  this.myService.doSomething().pipe(
    // disable when request completes/errors
    finalize(() => this.backgroundMode.disable()) 
  )
  .subscribe(() => console.log('Yaaaay, successful!'))
}, false);
```